# Help in finding articles/research papers regarding materials used for designing small PCBs

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I am currently working on an article for my internship on the topic of techniques for PCB design under space constraints. I am looking for the type of PCB materials that are used for manufacturing PCBs for small devices and how these materials affect the design. I searched on the internet for a long time but I couldn't find anything of relevance. Can someone help me in finding research materials that are relevant?

Comment: What makes you think the materials are any different? Define "small". I don't know what it is you're expecting to find either to be honest.

Comment: Have a look at the application notes and whitepapers of companies that fabricate space-constrained and high-density PCBs. It's in their best interest to sell you their services, so they're likely to have technical info that helps you become their customer by being familiar with the process and materials.

Comment: `I searched on the internet for a long time but I couldn't find anything of relevance` - please explain what search terms you were using because even the most badly related search terms I used delivered the goods in seconds. We're not daft on this site and I have to conclude that you might be slightly economical with the truth on this one.

Comment: The search answers are only limited by your imagination and key words. We used to make Ceramic hybrid RF amplifiers with discrete and IC and an RF shield about the size of a quarter. What are your key specs?

Comment: @DKNguyen by small I mean PCBs used in smart watches, sensor modules, hearing aids, oxymeter, etc. I am looking for materials that are used in manufacturing of PCBs that are used in these types of devices and why are those materials only used for manufacturing.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks for this suggestion. I will surely look into that.

Comment: Because of geometry for twist and warp, PCB's can be much thinner when small. Product material costs also need to be cheap like < 10% of market price

Comment: @Andyaka I used search terms like 'how does FR4 help in designing small pcbs' 'how does Polyimide substrate help in small pcb design' etc. These are just two examples of the search terms that I used.

Comment: I would think the same materials, but less of them.

Comment: @Hearth can you please explain ?

Comment: @BojackHorseman I don't see any reason to use different materials than normal PCBs, you'd just use smaller amounts of them because the PCB is smaller.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't have any key specs as such. I am just looking for materials that are used in designing small pcbs and why those materials are specifically used.

Comment: nothing exotic is used in small cheap devices but how they are used is what is more important and how it easily fits together in the package.  But there are exotic solutions with decades of R&D behind some of them.

Answer (score 2):

- that's a very good design question that deserves my upvote +1.

The best keyword search I can offer is **teardown** with any product you choose and specific materials you find interesting.

- examine in detail the materials used for interconnection of conductors and insulators.

e.g. [image]

https://www.microcontrollertips.com/teardown-a-simple-pulse-oximeter-for-home-healthcare-faq/
This is a common solution now for $20 on the web, so you must know the costed BOM is around $2 with a large [NRE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Non-recurring_engineering) cost for production startup.

### My advice

**Reverse яǝǝиi⅁иǝ anything and everything you can get your hands on.**

- learning to estimate the cost of Bills of Material or costed-BOMs was once part of my job while others estimate the **cost of production** in volume for machine time and labour. This takes experience.  But that was 40 years ago then 20 years ago , long before the vast information at your fingertips on the web.  So include **BOM** in [some of your searches.](https://www.google.com/search?q=electronics%20bom%20%20teardown)

some of my 10 second results

- https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMn3nXYwuNM

It's also a big business http://www.fomalhaut.co.jp/

Answer (score 2):

Search out **HDI PCBs** (high density interconnects) and semiconductor packaging techniques such as **chiplets**.
.

For non-consumer applications, hybrids have long been a mainstay.

And for cheap consumer goods, good old COB (chip-on-board) construction with a die or dies attached and wire-bonded directly to an ordinary (often single-layer) PCB.

Many, but not all, techniques are showcased in modern cellular phone designs. For example, some iPhones have a 161-pin BGA passive device that replaces 5 individual isolated inductors.

The difference in HDI PCBs is dramatic, not so much because the materials are so much different but because the line widths and multiple manufacturing operations allowing blind, buried, laser vias, via-in-pad and such like along with a large number of layers. The difference in pricing in prototype quantities compared to two layer PCBs is also dramatic, maybe 50:1 for the same area PCB.